# Dropbox restClient claims to save file correctly, but file does not exist when it should be loaded

Tags: ios, bundle, dropbox-api

I am new to iOS and trying to use the dropbox core API:

1) Download a file from dropbox

2) Collect the file from the folder it was saved and show it onscreen

The rest client claims the file loads successfully, but when I try to access it, it does not seem to exist. Here is what I'm doing:

Create directory locally and load the photos:

```
- (void)initDBPHotos
{
    NSString *directory = @"lobyPhotos";
    [self createDirecotry:directory];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,            
    NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:directory];
    for (DBMetadata *file in self.metaData.contents) {
        [self.restClient loadFile:file.path intoPath:fullPath];
    }
    [self loadPhotoArray:fullPath];
 }
```

Create the directory:

```
- (void)createDirecotry:(NSString *)dirName
{
    NSString *path;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dirName];
    NSError *error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path
                                   withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                    attributes:nil
                                                         error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
    }
  }
}
```

The restClient file loaded success method:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedFile:(NSString *)localPath
       contentType:(NSString *)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
    NSLog(@"File loaded into path: %@", localPath);
    int numFiles = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:localPath error:nil] count];
    NSLog(@"There are %d files in the local path", numFiles);

}
```

The result of this log is always 0 event though the loadedFile method always fires saying that it successfully loaded the file to the given path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
[self.restClient loadFile:file.path intoPath:fullPath];
```

Your `fullPath` isn't really a full path, it is a reference to a folder. You need to give an actual full path.

Try this:

```
for (DBMetadata *file in self.metaData.contents) {
    NSString *filename = [file.path lastPathComponent];
    NSString *destPath = [fullPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    [self.restClient loadFile:file.path intoPath:destPath];
}
```

Also be sure that the `lobyPhotos` folder has already been created inside the `Documents` folder.

Comment: Thank you that definitely helped, but now I am getting the following error:



DBRequest#connectionDidFinishLoading: error moving temp file to desired location: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)



Which I'm guessing is because I did not actually create a directory? I have checked that it exists though with:



- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory

Comment: Check that it is actually a directory. Your original code may have created a plain file with the name `lobyPhotos`. This needs to be deleted. Then be sure your code creates the folder at runtime if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you so much. I cannot tell you how much I appreciate you helping a newbie like me. I finally got it to work after ~6 hours! My biggest problem was thinking that I did not have to name the file locally while loading it into my directory.

Comment: @rmaddy By mistake i give the l fullPath on desktop, when I download data from dropbox my all data remove from desktop.. what can i do, to recover my all data from desktop.